# how to select data from a array sequentially

Tags: java, android, arrays, automation, appium

I have 3 emails

```
String[] emails = {"x@gmail.com", "y@gmail.com", "z@gmail.com"}
```

I want the code to select `x@gmail.com` first, `y@gmail.com` second, and `z@gmail.com` third, and plug it into this command :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']")).sendKeys(emails);`

But how do I make it so it selects `x@gmail.com` first, `y@gmail.com` second, and `z@gmail.com` last?

Comment: [`for-each`-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)?

Comment: start reading tutorials or search for this on SO.. plenty examples to find. I don't want to be sarcastic but this is noobish and you find the open door ***>[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)<*** !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

By looping over each email address in `emails` and calling your method one after the other. I would use a `for-each` loop. Read it like for each `String e` in `emails` call the method `sendKeys`.

```
for (String e : emails) { 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']"))
        .sendKeys(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator to sort them (that is if all emails are @gmail.com).

```
Arrays.sort(emails);
```

This would sort the array lexicographically and you can iterate over the array to get them from start - end

```
for (String email: emails){
    //Do your thing
}
```